# Get boolean from SQLite database leads to System.InvalidCastException in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a method that returns the stored value as an object from that specific type that it is stored in the database.

But if I'm trying to get a bool from my SQLite database (which it is stored as a "Boolean") the only thing that I get is an System.InvalidCastException at the *return reader.GetBoolean(index);* line. This only happens when I try to get a boolean.

My method for this is:

```
        public object GetDataByName(SQLiteDataReader reader, string name){
            int index = reader.GetOrdinal(name);
            TypeCode typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(reader.GetFieldType(index));

            switch(typeCode){
                case TypeCode.Int16: return Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt16(index));
                case TypeCode.Int32: return reader.GetInt32(index);
                case TypeCode.Int64: return Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt64(index));
                case TypeCode.String: return reader.GetString(index);
                case TypeCode.DateTime: return reader.GetDateTime(index);
                case TypeCode.Boolean: return reader.GetBoolean(index);
                default: return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no Boolean data type in SQLite. Boolean-like values are stored as 0 or 1.

Comment: SQLite has no types, much less booleans. What does your table contain? Whatever it is, you'll have to either parse it (if it's a string) or cast it (if it's a number with only 0/1 as possible values)

Comment: BTW what you try to do is already provided by the data reader's [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.item?view=net-5.0#System_Data_Common_DbDataReader_Item_System_String_) property. Your code doesn't return specific types, so it's little different than `var someObject=reader[name];`. It contains some casts that can result in overflow exceptions though

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Idk why but using the readers item property got me another exception which is not there anymore. So in the end it worked that easy.